# Hitting react-native-hms-analytics error TS1110: Type expected in node_modules folder

Tags: react-native, huawei-mobile-services

After adding "yarn add @hmscore/react-native-hms-analytics" to my react-native project, I'm hitting this error:

I've already have this in place, to force typescript to ignore node_modele folder =(

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": {
        "skipLibCheck": true
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"]
    ...
}
```

> node_modules/@hmscore/react-native-hms-analytics/src/index.d.ts:532:33
>
> - error TS1110: Type expected.
>
> 532         static onEvent(eventId: `${HAEventType}` | string, bundle:
> object): Promise;
> ~~~
>
> node_modules/@hmscore/react-native-hms-analytics/src/index.d.ts:532:66
>
> - error TS1005: ';' expected.
>
> 532         static onEvent(eventId: `${HAEventType}` | string, bundle:
> object): Promise;
>
> node_modules/@hmscore/react-native-hms-analytics/src/index.d.ts:564:1
>
> - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
>
> 564 }
> ~
>
> Found 105 errors.

Comment: Able to solve it by downgrading it from 6.9.0-302 to 6.2.0-301. Where can I find the release notes for each version please?

Comment: Noticed that 6.9.0-302 is using com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.9.0.302 while 6.2.0-301 is using com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:6.2.0.301. I still need to solve the above errors as they have added the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission